# asp kendo dropdown default value not using defined template

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

My kendo dropdown menu's currently selected index will only show up as "ShortName". 
If i expand the dropdown, it will correctly use the template "ShortName - Name". 
Why is the template not being used on the currently selected index?

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("SiteId")
.DataTextField("ShortName")
.Template("#: ShortName # - #: Name #")
.DataValueField("Id")
.DataSource(source =>
{
     source.Read(read =>
     {
         read.Action("GetSites", "Home");
     });
})
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[ValueTemplate](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/kendo.mvc.ui.fluent/dropdownlistbuilder#methods-ValueTemplate(System.String))** same as **Template**.

```
...
.Template("#: ShortName # - #: Name #")
.ValueTemplate("#: ShortName # - #: Name #")
...
```